# What does "Exited abnormally: Broken pipe: 13" on ios?

Tags: iphone, debugging, ipad

I got "Exited abnormally: Broken pipe: 13" while debug my ipad app.

When my app crashed for that error, I could not download device log from my pad while the console is working.

I wonder what does that mean?  Is there any method to get the log for the error?

Comment: What is the error string returned from `strerror(13);`?

Comment: strerror(13); is "Permission denied".  I'm also seeing this in my app, so I'm hunting down the offending code.